# Angular 2 Template syntax

Tags: javascript, angular

While reading online blog related to Angular2 I came across following syntax.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: require('./app.component.html'),
    styles: [require('./app.component.css')],
    directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ],        
 })
```

How does following two statements differs? What's role of require function here?

- template: require('./app.component.html')
- template: './app.component.html'

Does require in above statement loads html template asynchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does following two statements differs?

Well require is a part of CommonJS,The result of `require('./app.component.html')` will be the template string, 
but `templateUrl` field expects the PATH to the `.html` template.

so if you are going to use require than you have to use `template` instead of `templateUrl`.

there are various ways by whihc you can load your template

1. using require you have to assign to template like this :

   ```
   template: require('./app.component.html'),
   ```
2. using simple path like this :-

   ```
   templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
   ```
3. by setting `module.id` property in the @component annotation, by doing so angular will look at the current folder
   for template insetad of looking at the root. like this :

   ```
   @Component({
       selector: 'my-app',
       moduleId: module.id,
       templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
   })
   ```

see here for more info http://schwarty.com/2015/12/22/angular2-relative-paths-for-templateurl-and-styleurls/

Comment: Does this mean template: require('./app.component.html') statement will pull template file; read its contents as string and assign it to template at runtime? Or does it happen at compile time itself?

Comment: i dont know about runtime/compileTime ,but yes this statement will pull template as string and display as view.

Answer (score 0):

You can now load a module either synchronously or asynchronously. The synchronous way is the one defined in CommonJS and pretty straightforward –

```
var mymod = require('myModule');
// Call the exported function "hello()"
mymod.hello();
```

This is the synchronous way, Synchronous loading however blocks script execution until the module is loaded, so it might be better to load the module asynchronously:

```
require('myModule', function(mymod) {
    // Call the exported function hello
    mymod.hello(); 
});
```

You can do this way -

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
```

setting moduleId: module.id in the @Component decorator is the key here. If you don't have that then Angular 2 will be looking for your files at the root level.So you dont need require() anymore . Hope it will help :)